# Ubuntu desktop environment isn't working

Tags: 18.04, login, desktop-environments, wayland, amdgpu-pro

I have installed many desktop environments, but my default Ubuntu session isn't working. I can only login using Ubuntu with Wayland. I want to login with the other options which are shown below. I tried to install an AMD graphics driver on my laptop and lost all of them except for Ubuntu with Wayland.

The default Ubuntu session was working. I've been using this Ubuntu installation since 2011, and always upgraded to the next LTS release when it came out. I purchased a Dell Inspiron 5570 that has AMD Radeon 530 discrete graphics and replaced my hard drive. I have upgraded 16.04 to 18.04 on my Dell Inspiron 5570. The problem began after I have tried to install an AMD driver. I haven't had a single serious problem in last 8 years, but now just one AMD graphics driver is creating a lot of trouble.

Results of `lspci -nn | grep -E 'VGA|Display'` :

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 [8086:5917] (rev 07) 
01:00.0 Display controller [0380]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260/M265 / M340/M360 / M440/M445] [1002:6900] (rev c1)
```

[image: IMG:]
<sup>**Ubuntu 18.04 login screen**</sup>

**System info**

OS: Ubuntu 18.04 bionic
  Kernel: x86_64 Linux 4.15.0-43-generic
  Uptime: 23m
  Packages: 3121
  Shell: bash 4.4.19
  Resolution: 3840x1080
  DE: GNOME
  WM: GNOME Shell
  WM Theme: Adwaita
  GTK Theme: Ambiance [GTK2/3]
  Icon Theme: ubuntu-mono-dark
  Font: Ubuntu 11
  CPU: Intel Core i7-8550U @ 8x 4GHz [25.0°C]
  GPU: intel

Comment: can you eloborate more.. many themes means.. GTK.. gnome-shell, icons etc?

Comment: I am adding a picture in reply. I can only login using Ubuntu on Wayland Desktop Environment. I want to login at Ubuntu. I have tried to install AMD driver on my laptop and lost all of them.

Comment: before installing new Desktop Environments, has the default Ubuntu session worked? or since Default Session is not working you installed different Environments?

Comment: The default Ubuntu Session Was working. I am using this ubuntu installation from 2011 and always upgrade to LTS when it comes out. I purchased dell 5570 and replaced my hard drive. I have upgraded 16.04 to 18.04 on Dell Inspiron 5570. The problem begins as I have tried to install AMD driver. I got not a single serious propblem in last 8 years but now just one driver creating a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Only the Wayland login option works since installing the [amdgpu-pro-18.20-673703-ubuntu-18.04.tar.xz](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-prorad-lin-18-20) (proprietary AMDGPU-PRO) graphics driver, so [uninstall the proprietary AMDGPU-PRO graphics driver](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/faq/gpu-635) and reboot the laptop.

The following command will provide you with the version of the AMDGPU-Pro stack on your system, or inform you that there are no packages found:

```
dpkg -l amdgpu-pro
```

`ubuntu-drivers list` will show which graphics driver is installed. Open the terminal and type:

```
ubuntu-drivers list
```

After you uninstall the non-working AMDGPU-PRO graphics driver, you can run this command to see what graphics driver Ubuntu 18.04 recommends for your Dell Inspiron 5570, if any.

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
```

If `ubuntu-drivers devices` doesn't recommend installing anything, then don't install anything.

Reinstall Xorg (*xserver-xorg*).

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq xserver-xorg  
sudo reboot
```

It's not necessary to reconfigure Xorg. Click the gear icon at login and choose a Xorg session. After that the laptop will always boot to Xorg until you click the gear icon at login again and choose a Wayland session.

Comment: It is not working. I have been tried this before.

Comment: Dell Inspiron 5570 has an AMD Radeon 530 discrete graphics.

Comment: lspci -nn | grep -E 'VGA|Display'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 [8086:5917] (rev 07)
01:00.0 Display controller [0380]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260/M265 / M340/M360 / M440/M445] [1002:6900] (rev c1)

Comment: I have uninstalled Radeon Driver. Now only Intel Driver is working.

Comment: OS: Ubuntu 18.04 bionic
  Kernel: x86_64 Linux 4.15.0-43-generic
  Uptime: 23m
  Packages: 3121
  Shell: bash 4.4.19
  Resolution: 3840x1080
  DE: GNOME 
 WM: GNOME Shell
 WM Theme: Adwaita
 GTK Theme: Ambiance [GTK2/3]
 Icon Theme: ubuntu-mono-dark
 Font: Ubuntu 11
 CPU: Intel Core i7-8550U @ 8x 4GHz [25.0°C]
 GPU: intel

Comment: There is not any AMD Driver.

Comment: "ubuntu-drivers list" and "ubuntu-drivers devices" do not show any output.

Comment: I have downloaded it from AMD Website. amdgpu-pro-18.20-673703-ubuntu-18.04.tar.xz

Comment: sudo: amdgpu-pro-uninstall: command not found

Comment: I am in search of some way to reinstall or reconfigure that Xorg? I am feeling X better than Wayland because sometimes I have more than 10 ssh screens at once. If there is some way to reconfigure or reinstall Xorg. I am not feeling comfortable with this Wayland. I have lot of sticky notes, logs, manuals at my screen, and, everything is disturbed now. According to my experience, the problem is with Xorg, not with ubuntu Desktop environment itself.

Comment: It's not necessary to reconfigure Xorg. Click the gear icon at login and choose a Xorg session. After that the laptop will always boot to Xorg until you click the gear icon at login again and choose a Wayland session.

Comment: The problem is that Xorg session is not loading.